# how can I make my elasticsearch allow CROS origin on a server

Tags: elasticsearch, cross-domain, cross-origin-read-blocking

When I try to add any of these parameters:

```
http.cors.enabled : true

http.cors.allow-origin : "*"
http.cors.allow-methods : OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers : X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type, Content-Length

http.jsonp.enable: true
```

to elasticsearch.yml elasticsearch fail to start.
by the way, I added `xpack.security.enabled: true` beforehand.
is there something wrong with what I wrote or is there something else I am not seeing?
please help me find a solution to CROS origin for elasticsearch.

Comment: Which Elasticsearch version you use?

Comment: version : 7.5.2

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html

Comment: Is there a specific error output when elasticsearch fails to start? (Check the logs) If so please share it.

Comment: it was my mistake, instead of cros i wrote cors, thank you all for helping me